# ASP.Net Core 2 - Query SQL without EFCore?

Tags: sql, asp.net-core-2.0, ef-core-2.0

I'm new to Core 2 and am trying to connect to a SQL server to query some info.

I cant get EFCore to scaffold the database because it's an old DB with badly designed links, the scaffold kicks it out and won't work.

I can't alter the tables, it's read only.  how can i get this to work, or, can i access the db in a different way?  I cant find anything on google that doesn't use efcore.

Thanks,

Comment: You could use Dapper if you just want to query the DB.

Comment: you dont have to use EF you could do it all the long way with stored procedures and creating classes to mirror a row in the database

Comment: You can drop down to standard ADO.NET as you're probably used to from previous development. .NET Core 2.0 has full support now. As @gsharp mentioned, Dapper is also an option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of solutions to achieve this. Since ASP.NET Core 2.0 implements .NET Standard 2.0, you can use ADO.NET with ASP.NET Core. So you can write stored procedure or query to get your data with dataset or datareader.

There are also other lightweight ORM tools like Dapper or NPoco. Both these ORMs allow developers to write SQL queries. Please refer to below posts to find out how to use them with ASP.NET Core

- [Use Dapper ORM With ASP.NET Core](http://www.talkingdotnet.com/use-dapper-orm-with-asp-net-core/)
- [Use NPoco ORM With ASP.NET Core](http://www.talkingdotnet.com/use-npoco-orm-with-asp-net-core/)